# Rails timezone and Daylight saving time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

for a while I´m trying to understand how this timezone times will work, and I had a question:

Today in my country, we are in  Daylight saving time (GMT-2). 
So the user of my application enter a time, like 11:00AM and post the form.
Far as I know, rails will convert this date to UTC and save in the database (mysql in my case), like: 01:00PM UTC.

When I recover that record, I had to convert to local time to display. Ok?

My question is, lets suppose that this date/time represents a date/time in future, when my country gets out from summer time (GMT-3). Rails will save 01:00PM UTC? Today, in  Daylight saving time, how will be the local time? And in the future, how will be this local time?

Basically, I always need to display to user 11:00AM.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 months after you asked, but perhaps `skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes=` will help - it tells AcitveRecord not to convert timezones on storage or retrieval. See [ActiveRecord Timestamp](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html) which shows the example:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:written_on]
end
```

Answer (score 14):

There are several places where timezone can come into play: the operating system (or probably user account) default setting, the database server, Rails `environment.rb`.

The key is to make sure all dates are *stored* with UTC time zone, then displayed in whatever your local timezone is.  It sounds like you're doing that.

So your question seems to boil down to "if it's Daylight time, I want to offset by -3 hours, else offset by -2 hours".  The Rails time extensions let you determine your current offset like `Time.zone.now.utc_offset`, and `Time#dst?` tells you if it's Daylight Savings Time with those two you can conditionally subtract the extra hour (3600 hundred seconds).

Comment: So, it is a question of display, always. All date values passed to a filter parameter needs to be converted to UTC in this case.

Comment: That's the right way to think about it, although maybe my choice of words "displayed" wasn't helpful.  I had a case a few weeks ago where a partner ran a job at 2am (regardless of DST offset), meaning we needed to coordinate with that.  In truth it doesn't matter what timezone the date is stored as *as long as it contains the timezone* -- if you know your own timezone and that of the stored date, you have everything you need to adjust the time and display it however you need.  Storing dates as UTC (and setting systems to UTC) just makes it all easier.

Comment: Well, lets supose that now we are in DST and we save a record at 8am local time. This will save a 10am utc in database. In another hand, supose that now is normal time and we save a record at 8am local time, saving 11am utc in database. It´s not possible to display both record as 8am to the user. Now, if we set all to UTC will work.

Comment: How you choose to display the timezone offset to the user is up to you.  Typically people think in their current local time, not in UTC, and except for twice a year the distinction between daylight and standard times isn't particularly relevant.  Your use-case may be different.  But I believe my answer provides the keys to whatever solution you decide is right.  If you spend some time clarifying your question, I'll be happy to take another attempt at understanding and responding.

Comment: Ok, just to finish, there is a way to save the datetime information exactly in the local time format ? In other words, force to be no transformations ?