# PDT vs PST in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, time

So I don't want to start a code-religious war (see all other comments on this topic in the internet). I just really need my app to work.

Right now I call

```
Time.zone = starting_point.time_zone
params[:trip][:leaving_at] = Time.zone.parse(params[:leaving_at_date] + " " + params[:leaving_at_time]).utc
```

and set this as the leaving_at time of a trip.

I then create some child trips on different days and I intend for them to leave at the same time as the parent trip so I do this:

```
@child_trip.leaving_at = Time.parse(new_date + " " + trip_params[:leaving_at].to_time.to_s).utc
```

Then I want to die, because this is in PST time and the first is in PDT time. Hence it is displayed as 8am in one and 7am in another. I live in california, but the complaint came from the midwest, and I have duplicated it everywhere. The parent is always 1 hour ahead  of the children.

I don't care how rails is SUPPOSED or OUGHT to work. I just want to fix this problem?

I've tried:

1. Time.zone = starting_point.time_zone
2. Time.zone.now
3. Time.parse( . . ., true) - for the "now" attribute of Time.parse
4. adding and removing the little .utc at the end of my Time.parse calls (I don't think it matters either way.
5. throwing my computer at the floor.

no luck yet

If I had to say it, Rails is not being very smart or magical in this case. Rails should just be saving everything as UTC no matter what. When I say Time.zone = starting_point.time_zone why would it do PDT in one and PST in another? There is no difference to UTC. All the code is in the same controller, literally 4 lines below inside of an each block.

I appreciate anyone who can help.

here's another post on this topic where the questioner is just pounced on [Rails timezone and Daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378327/rails-timezone-and-daylight-saving-time)

Comment: date time are stored in utc, unless you code the contrary. You have to set the timezone for the request and it would be respected

Comment: What is stored in your database? Is there any time zone information?

Comment: The leaving_at time is stored like this: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 00:00:38 UTC +00:00 in UTC, but something is at first respecting DST and then not.

Comment: Supposedly this issue is solved https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5559  http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails but I'm still having it.